# Can't find an explanation for koa.js workshop solution, exercise number one

Tags: javascript, generator, koa, co

It has to be rather simple, but I can't understand the solution for [the beginning exercise from koa workshop](https://github.com/koajs/workshop/tree/master/01-co).

The test:

```
var co = require('co');
var assert = require('assert');
var fs = require('./index.js');

describe('.stats()', function () {
  it('should stat this file', co(function* () {
    var stats = yield fs.stat(__filename);
    assert.ok(stats.size);
  }));
});
```

The solution and the task:

```
var fs = require('fs');

/**
 * Create a yieldable version of `fs.stat()`:
 *
 *   app.use(function* () {
 *     var stats = yield exports.stat(__filename);
 *   })
 *
 * Hint: you can return a yieldable.
 */

exports.stat = function (filename) {
    return function (done) {
        fs.stat(filename, done);
    }
};
```

The way I think of this test is: `co` library runs the generator function for us, the `fs.stat(__filename)` invokes, returns the

```
function (done) {
    fs.stat(filename, done);
}
```

Then, all I have are questions: why does anonymous function returns `fs.stat()` at the same place and where does it take `done` callback? I have logged this callback out, it's generators `next()` method with `stats` object as a passing parameter, but I can't find any information about callbacks injection in `co`. How does this work? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wasn't able to find this information on the main `README.md`, but it looks like `co` provides a callback to **thunks** automatically. So in the example above `co` provides the `done` callback and invokes the:

```
function (done) {
    fs.stat(filename, done);
}
```

If there is an error this callback expects that the main function would return error (`done(err);`), if everything is ok: `done(null, result);`. After that the result is passed to generator. Here is the `done` callback code:

```
function () {
  if (called) return;
  called = true;
  next.apply(ctx, arguments);
}
```

Well, let's return to the solution. The `co`'s git `README.md` says:

> Thunk support only remains for backwards compatibility and may be removed in future versions of `co`.

So let's rewrite it to the modern view with promises:

```
exports.stat = function(filename) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.stat(filename, (err, stats) => {
      if (err) {reject(err);}
      resolve(stats);
    });
  });
};
```

We wrap the promise with the anonymous function which get the `filename` value and encapsulates it for the returning promise object, which is one of the supported **yieldables** in `co`. This promise starts the `fs.stat` with the callback. This callback `resolve`s the promise if everything is ok, or `reject`s it otherwise. The `resolve`d result returns into the generator.